# regex for time validation

Tags: php, regex, time

I want to validate a time with a regex. I created the following expression :

```
'#^([01][0-9])|(2[0-4])(:[0-5][0-9]){1,2}$#'
```

Here is the problem:

```
<?php
var_dump(preg_match('#^([01][0-9])|(2[0-4])(:[0-5][0-9]){1,2}$#', '14:25'));
// Returns 1 (OK)

var_dump(preg_match('#^([01][0-9])|(2[0-4])(:[0-5][0-9]){1,2}$#', '25:25'));
// Returns 0 (OK)

var_dump(preg_match('#^([01][0-9])|(2[0-4])(:[0-5][0-9]){1,2}$#', '14:2555'));
// Returns 1 (instead of 0 as I would like to get)
?>
```

Does anybody know what is wrong?

Comment: can you give examples of what you expect?

Comment: Here are some examples: 
    14:25 OK,
    25:30 KO,
    14:65 KO,
    14:59 OK,
    14:34:43 OK

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you should be aware that there is no valid time as 24:*nn*

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Time in 24-Hour format regular expression pattern :

```
([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?
```

The 24-hour clock format is start from 0-23 or 00-23 then a semi colon (:) and follow by 00-59 then (optionally a semi colon (:) and follow by 00-59).

Description :

```
(                  # start of group #1
  [01]?[0-9]       # start with 0-9,1-9,00-09,10-19
  |                # or
  2[0-3]           # start with 20-23
)                  # end of group #1
:                  # follow by a semi colon (:)
[0-5][0-9]         # follow by 0..5 and 0..9, which means 00 to 59
(                  # start of group #2
  :                # follow by a semi colon (:)
  [0-5][0-9]       # follow by 0..5 and 0..9, which means 00 to 59
)                  # end of group #2
?                  # optional third part
```

Matching time formats :

```
01:00, 02:00, 13:00,
 1:00,  2:00, 13:01,
23:59, 15:00,
00:00,  0:00,
14:34:43, 01:00:00
```

Not matching time formats :

```
 24:00             # hour is out of range [0-23]
 12:60             # minute is out of range [00-59]
  0:0              # invalid format for minute, at least 2 digits
 13:1              # invalid format for minute, at least 2 digits
  0:00:0           # invalid format for seconds, at least 2 digits
101:00             # hour is out of range [0-23]
```

Example :

```
var_dump(preg_match('#^[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?$#', '14:25'));    // OK
var_dump(preg_match('#^[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?$#', '25:25'));    // KO
var_dump(preg_match('#^[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?$#', '25:30'));    // KO
var_dump(preg_match('#^[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?$#', '14:2555'));  // KO
var_dump(preg_match('#^[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?$#', '14:65'));    // KO
var_dump(preg_match('#^[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?$#', '14:59'));    // OK
var_dump(preg_match('#^[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?$#', '14:34:43')); // OK
```

Comment: Looks like the OP wishes to match 14:25:55 as a valid time as well.

Comment: It now takes into account the third part of the tme format ;)

Comment: +1 for the solution (that's been accepted by the OP) with working examples.  That said, am still at a loss to explain *why* the OP's attempt matches 14:2555 when the pattern included ^ and $ anchors.

Answer (score 6):

```
^(([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?)$
```

This will get from 00:00 to 23:59 and 00:00:00 to 23:59:59.

Comment: preg_match('/^(([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?)$/', $time, $matches);

Answer (score 2):

Alternation is a low-precedence operator, so wrap it in a non-capture group:

```
    #^(?:([01][0-9])|(2[0-3]))(:[0-5][0-9]){1,2}$#
      +++                    +
```

See demo [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%28?%3a%28%5B01%5D%5B0-9%5D%29%7C%282%5B0-4%5D%29%29%28%3a%5B0-5%5D%5B0-9%5D%29%7B1,2%7D%24&input=14:25%0D%0A25:25%0D%0A14:2555%0D%0A14:25:55).

Answer (score 1):

```
/(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?/
```

This will allow 00:00 or 00:00:00 as well, some of the others here don't.

It also limits the time to 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 or 23:59, some of the others allow 24:00 or 25:00, etc.